# Does a grammatical error in a license annul the statement?

Tags: licensing, language

In a license for commercial software, I have recently encountered the following <s>perl</s> pearl of perspicuous and immaculate syntax:

> [company] does not warrant that use of the Software will operate uninterrupted or error free.

Since *use* cannot *operate* in any sense, shall the whole sentence be annuled and the license treated as if without it?

Comment: "Perl" is a programming language, you should have used "pearl", does that detract from the intent of your question and should therefore be invalidated?

Comment: @RonBeyer a typo is more pardonable than a semantic-syntatical error that keeps the syntax formally correct but turns the meaning into utter [gibberish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabberwocky). Cannot one insist on literal reading of the license?

Comment: No, you cannot. Law has always been about *intent*, not the literal word.

Comment: This is a different question but about the same sentence, so let me know if I had better ask it separately. Can the sentence be interpreted as refusing responsibility for bugs in the software? Or does it mean simply that bugs may be present, as they always are, and the obligations to fix bugs may be stated elsewhere in the license?

Comment: It simply says that the software is not guaranteed to operate "error free" or "uninterrupted". They aren't refusing responsibility (that may be spelled out elsewhere), they are just trying to say that "this might crash or produce incorrect results". Otherwise somebody like me might stick it in an industrial control system and start suing people when the software crashes and the system malfunctions.

Comment: Thank you, Ron. You have used *guarantee* where the original had *warrant*. Are their meanings identical in this context?

Comment: In this context they would be, yes.

Comment: It's impossible to do that because vernacular changes over time. Law writings can be sloppy if the intent is clear (and even that changes over time). Most law tries to avoid colloquial terms but there isn't anything wrong with writing a contract (which this is) in any method that conveys the appropriate intent, regardless of the format it is presented in. Lawyers and laymen aren't linguists, and shouldn't need to be held to that standard.

Comment: I mean basic literacy, or the ability to express one's thoughts correctly. It does not require a degree in linguistics. The sentence in question makes no sense in any dialect of English, past or present. @user6726 Yeah, I am a terrible typist, but not so bad a grammarian for a non-native speaker :-)

Comment: There have been cases where a tiny mistake _changed the meaning_ of a term in a contract (there was a case of a faulty comma costing someone more than $10 million), but in this case the meaning is not changed, so the contract stands.

Comment: Your stance is the legal equivalent of [this skit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmVnr7rsWrE) ;-).

Comment: @gnasher729 Core constitutional provisions [stand or fall with a comma...](https://www.nytimes.com/2007/12/16/opinion/16freedman.html)

Comment: @RonBeyer What if it actually creates ambiguities (unlike this case). See https://www.nytimes.com/2018/02/09/us/oxford-comma-maine.html

Comment: @KodosJohnson Ambiguities in a contract are often viewed in favor of the party that did **not** draft the contract, such was the case with the link you cited.

Comment: If your **use of the software** does not function as anticipated, then it has failed to **operate** (intransitive verb: ["to produce an appropriate effect"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/operate)) correctly.  It would appear that "use" *can* "operate"...

Comment: If anything, [that sentence has been used by multiple companies](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22does+not+warrant+that+use+of+the+Software+will+operate+uninterrupted+or+error+free%22).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107548/discussion-on-question-by-ant-222-does-a-grammatical-error-in-a-license-annul-th).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> company does not warrant that use of the Software will operate
>   uninterrupted or error free.

A court will not find that statement to be ambiguous or contradictory. Mere grammatical differences will not void a contract. See [Typing errors in legal contract](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/typing-errors-in-legal-contract)

> I have recently encountered the following perl of perspicuous and
>   immaculate syntax:

Correct grammar and usage is "pearl", not "perl". [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) is a programming language; as for a pearl, you must be thinking of the [definition of Pearl Of Wisdom (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pearl%20of%20wisdom).

Comment: And anyway, an awful lot of what lawyers consider correct grammar (for example, omitted punctuation) would be considered incorrect in any other context. You can't judge legal language by the standards of ordinary plain English.

Comment: @MichaelKay do you mean parenthetical expressions? I believe the commas are removed to make them inseparable from the surrounding sentece,  and I have no grudge about it.

Answer (score 13):

> Since *use* cannot *operate* in any sense, shall the whole sentence be annuled and the license treated as if without it?

No. The statement is intelligible enough for a reasonable person would grasp the substance thereof; namely, that the company cannot be held liable for software interruptions or bugs. Therefore, the sentence is not to be voided or stricken.

Licenses and contracts in general are premised --*inter alia*-- on the parties' awareness of the conditions, not on the grammatical correctness of how these are expressed.

Comment: I would say rather than on the parties' awareness, on what a reasonable person's interpretation would be. The two can be in conflict, but it will generally be the latter which will prevail.

Comment: @JBentley The criterion of reasonable person's interpretation is relevant where there is no evidence of how the parties understood (and thus became aware of) the binding terms. The context given by the OP most likely fits that scenario. But if evidence shows that the parties had a specific understanding when forming the contract, there is no need to assess how a reasonable person would interpret *their* contract.